# JMeter jmx file corrupted

Tags: apache, jmeter

I've been making a test plan in jMeter, saved it, and now can't open it back up. It turns out the .jmx file has become corrupted. Here's the error log:

```
---- Debugging information ----
message             :  : no more data available - expected end tags </intProp></ConstantThroughputTimer></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <intProp> from line 464 and start tag <ConstantThroughputTimer> from line 463 and start tag <hashTree> from line 429 and start tag <hashTree> from line 387 and start tag <hashTree> from line 35 and start tag <hashTree> from line 19 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</intProp>\n              <doubleProp... @465:26
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
cause-message       :  : no more data available - expected end tags </intProp></ConstantThroughputTimer></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <intProp> from line 464 and start tag <ConstantThroughputTimer> from line 463 and start tag <hashTree> from line 429 and start tag <hashTree> from line 387 and start tag <hashTree> from line 35 and start tag <hashTree> from line 19 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</intProp>\n              <doubleProp... @465:26
class               : org.apache.jmeter.timers.ConstantThroughputTimer
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.timers.ConstantThroughputTimer
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[10]/hashTree/ConstantThroughputTimer
line number         : 465
class[1]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
```

So I checked the jmx file and sure enough, just after the ConstantThroughputTimer the bottom half of the config is missing. Weird! No idea why this has happened. 
Has anyone else experienced this or know how to fix the issue so this doesn't happen again?

For reference I'm using jMeter 2.11 with JDK1.8.0_05 and JRE8 on Windows 7.

Comment: File corruption may be totally unrelated to jmeter.

Comment: Not exactly this, but a similar problem is usually happening to me when I use XML results. I fix it manually, but then again I only have to place an end tag at the very end of the xml, your case seems to be more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed similar thing where my test plans get corrupted after saving using jmeter build 2.11.r1554548 (build on December 31 2013). Looks like jmeter bug.

The work around is to remove ConstantThroughputTimer from the test plan. Save works perfectly.

I tried to use latest nightly build of jmeter. I downloaded apache-jmeter-r1613102 (build on July 18 2014) and is still corupting the test plan file with ConstantThroughputTimer in the testing plan.

Comment: Same behaviour on my machine. Are you using a non us/en machine?